# Import stuff from TypeScripd declaration file with only "declare module" top level declarations

Tags: typescript, module, bridge.net

I've got a TypeScript file foo.d.ts. It contains a lot of "declare module" constructs and nothing more:

```
declare module Foo {
}

declare module Fun {
}
```

The code is auto-generated by the Bridge.NET, so I can't modify it (I can, actually. But it is not a good-looking solution).

If the file is referenced in another one with `import * as bridge from "./foo";` the tsc says that "File foo.d.ts is not a module". What I'm doing wrong?

If I edit the generated file (foo.d.ts) and add to the end of it dummy top-level export (`export interface Fix {}`) the problem disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error you've got is that your **foo.d.ts** is not actually a module, it's a script. But *import* statement is supposed to be used with modules only. When you added `export interface Fix {}`, this transformed the file into a module and that is why the error had gone.

The common rule is pretty simple, TypeScript compiler treats a file as a module if there is at least one top-level entity (class/interface/variable ..) containing **export** modifier. Otherwise, the file will be processed just like a script.

If you don't really need **foo.d.ts** to be a module, you can refer it using the directive below. In this case all entities declared in the file will be globally available.

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />
```